# Migrating zip files to directories using certain label

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

**Introduction:**

I'm a novice to scripting and made the decision to change from Windows to Ubuntu(Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) recently so I'm not familiar with many things. An explanation or advice would be greatly appreciated if possible.

**Problem:**

I have a directory full of projects labeled which I would like to relocate based on the subject. Sometimes certain labels are missing because they didn't apply.

The general structure is:
("CODE")["SUBJECT"("USER")]"GenericProjectName".zip

Most simple structure is:
["SUBJECT"]"GenericProjectName".zip

I would like to move the files from the directory "OLD" to "NEW/SUBJECT".

**Directory structure:**

MAIN
----OLD
--------("CODE")["SUBJECT"("USER")]"GenericProjectName".zip
--------("CODE")["SUBJECT"("USER")]"GenericProjectName".zip
----NEW
--------"SUBJECT"

Comment: Read `man mv` and use the `--target-directory=` option. Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Good that you mentioned that I forgot to change that and thanks for the checker tip. I made the edit in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
For each zip file, I get the filename and get "SUBJECT" using awk. After extracting the subject I make a directory with the name and move the file into it. Because it's a bash script I can more easily use the variables needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.zip
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    dirname=`echo "$filename" | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}'`
    mkdir -p "$dirname" &&
    mv -iv "$file" "$dirname"
done
```